# Friction on car tires

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

In tipler and mosca 5th edition the following passage occurs:

[image]

I am a bit confused by the sentence starting "If the power delivered by the engine is small enough...". I am not seeing why the power being small means the wheels do not slip. Wouldn't the wheels not slip if the power is large as well? (I am taking "slip" to mean that the wheels slide on the ground)

Answer (score 2):

The static frictional force $f_{\rm s}\le  \mu_{\rm s} \,m \,g$ is accelerating the centre of mass of the car which is traveling with a velocity $\vec v$.
This means that the power delivered to accelerate the car has to be $\le  \mu_{\rm s}\, m \,g\, v$ if the no slipping condition is to be satisfied .

Answer (score 1):

> I am not seeing why the power being small means the wheels do not
>   slip. Wouldn't the wheels not slip if the power is large as well?

[image: Friction]

The weight of the car causes the wheel(s) to experience a normal force $N$.

Now we try and accelerate the car by applying torque (clockwise) to the wheel's axel, call it $\tau_a$.

This results in a friction force $F_f$ that attempts to prevent the wheel's contact point to slide over the road surface.

Simplistically, the friction force can be modeled as:

$$F_f=\mu N$$

where $\mu$ is a friction coefficient.  As mentioned by @JTS in the comments, $\mu$ is somewhat variable and has a maximum value. It shouldn't be seen as a proper constant.

The friction force exerts a counter-clockwise torque $\tau_f$ about the centre of the wheel, with radius $R$:

$$\tau_f=\mu NR$$

As long as:

$$\tau_f=\tau_a$$

That is:

$$\boxed{\mu NR=\tau_a}$$

Then no slippage occurs. But for higher torques $\tau_a$, slippage will occur, because:

$$\mu NR<\tau_a$$

Of course $\tau_a$ is related to the power $P$ delivered to the wheel(s), as follows:

$$P=\tau_a \omega$$

where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the wheel(s).

Comment: In the last equations you mean $\tau_a$ rather than $\sigma_a$

Comment: Oooopsie. I'm correcting that now.

Comment: And on topic I would make explicit the observation that $\mu$ is variable and has a maximum value (vague and rough idea: weak bonds are strained and then broken), which is implicitly contained in your nice answer.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must also remember the difference between Power and Force, and the book is a bit confusing about that.

As written by @gert , the no-slipping condition is determined by the torque applied on the wheels; Maximal force the wheel can exert is $\mu F_n$

But the power (Kilowatt, Horsepower) is $W = F \cdot v$ , force multiplied by speed.
Hence the actual power to be used depends on the speed.  At high speed ($v$ large) you can use a lot of power without the wheels slipping.

At low speed, with little power you can make the tyres slip. In practical experience, car wheels are easily slipping at start (with low gear) while do not slip at high speed. In theory, starting from still, you should initially use zero power ($v = 0$) .
Since combustion engines are not good at zero speed - zero power, a clutch is introduced to absorb energy and deliver a limited force.